# Phaser 3 : Add arguments to callback functions (time event, keyboard event)

Tags: javascript, callback, keyboard, arguments, phaser-framework

I'm developing a game on Phaser 3 and I'm currently struggling on callback use. 
I have created two classes, one called "Entitee" and the other one called "objet"

```
class Entitee extends Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite{
    constructor(scene, x, y, pv, mana, speed, poise, asset){
    //Private
        var _pv = pv;
        var _pvMax = pv;
        var _mana = mana;
        var _manaMax = mana;
        var _speed = speed;
        var _poise = poise;
        var _asset = asset;

        super(scene, x, y, _asset);

        scene.add.existing(this);
        scene.physics.world.enableBody(this);
    //Public

        this.hurt = function(objet){
              console.log(_pv);
              console.log(objet);
              _pv += objet.getPvMod();
              console.log(_pv);
        }
    }//END CONSTRUCTOR
}

class Objet {
    constructor(name, price, range, cd, ammo, lag, pvMod, manaMod, poiseMod, speedMod, animAtt, animZone){
        var _name = name;
          var _price = price;
          var _range = range;
          var _cooldown = cd;
          var _ammo = ammo;
          var _direction;
          var _lag = lag;
          var _pvMod = pvMod;
          var _manaMod = manaMod;
          var _poiseMod = poiseMod;
          var _speedMod = speedMod;
          var _animAtt = animAtt;
          var _animZone = animZone;

        this.getName= function(){ return _name};
        this.getPrice= function(){ return _price};
        this.getRange= function(){ return _range};
        this.getCooldown= function(){ return _cooldown};
        this.getAmmo= function(){return _ammo};
        this.getDirection = function(){return _direction};
        this.getPvMod = function(){return _pvMod};
        this.getManaMod = function(){return _manaMod};
        this.getPoiseMod = function(){return _poiseMod};
        this.getSpeedMod = function(){return _speedMod};
        this.getAnimAtt = function(){return _animAtt};
        this.getAnimZone = function(){return _animZone};
    }

}
```

Now i'm trying to get my entitee (entity in English) hurt by an object i created, called "hammer". But i would like to be able to get it hurts by many different object.
I try to get it hurt when I press "P" and/or every 1 sec.
But I can't found how to give to the callback function the object I want the entity to get hurt with.

```
class Scene1 extends Phaser.Scene{
    constructor() {
        super("Scene1")
      }
//>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> INIT
init(){
}

//>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> PRELOAD
preload(){
}

//>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> CREATE
create(){


  this.joueur = new Entitee(this, 100, 100, 100, 10, 200, 42, "square");
  this.hammer = new Objet("Hammer", 12, 12, 12, 12, 0, -10, 0, 10, "empty", "empty");

  this.timer_test = this.time.addEvent({ delay: 1000, callback: this.joueur.hurt, args: [this.joueur, this.hammer], loop: true });


  this.input.keyboard.on('keydown-P', this.joueur.hurt, this.joueur, this.hammer);
  this.joueur.hurt(this.hammer);


}//END CREATE

//>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> UPDATE
update(){
}//END UPDATE

}//END SCENE
```

i have `this.joueur.hurt(this.hammer);` working.

`this.timer_test = this.time.addEvent({ delay: 1000, callback: this.joueur.hurt, args: [this.joueur, this.hammer], loop: true });` send me the following error :

```
Entitee.js:60 Uncaught TypeError: objet.getPvMod is not a function
    at Function.Entitee.hurt (Entitee.js:60)
    at Clock.update (phaser.js:183771)
    at EventEmitter.emit (phaser.js:1774)
    at Systems.step (phaser.js:35504)
    at SceneManager.update (phaser.js:77851)
    at Game.step (phaser.js:139643)
    at TimeStep.step (phaser.js:67227)
    at step (phaser.js:67474)
```

And when I press "p" i get

```
Entitee.js:60 Uncaught TypeError: objet.getPvMod is not a function
    at Entitee.hurt (Entitee.js:60)
    at KeyboardPlugin.emit (phaser.js:1752)
    at KeyboardPlugin.update (phaser.js:166926)
    at EventEmitter.emit (phaser.js:1751)
    at onKeyDown (phaser.js:71462)
```

I figure how to avoid callback functions but it would be so easiest if I may give to those callback the arguments I want. 
I've been lurking around internet for solutions but none of it have been useful. Some people seems to use console.log() but I can't understand why and how.

Thanks for considering my issue !

Sheolis

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that args should be just `[this.hammer]` since we don't need `joueur` as input to the `hurt` function

```
      this.timer_test = this.time.addEvent({ 
                                   delay: 1000, 
                                   callback: this.joueur.hurt, 
                                   args: [this.hammer], 
                                   loop: true });
```

You may also look at `callbackScope` at the [docs](https://rexrainbow.github.io/phaser3-rex-notes/docs/site/timer/).